# Cloud Data Fusion - my pipeline is not self aware

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

What's the best practice to declare, store and reuse variables during the runtime of a data pipeline ?

How to get pipeline name from the code inside the pipeline ?

I am creating ETL templates here, needs to work smoothly without too many

Answer (score 1):

you can set runtime arguments for Macros:
https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/1188036746/Runtime+Arguments

Comment: Thank you Sean. That looks more like app preferences an initial parameters setting. I need this to be dynamic. Let me read through to see if it works for me. I also don't want to store these variables in a storage, needs to be stored in memory and available only during the the runtime.

At the start of the pipeline, I am creating an ID of this run. manually which is not ideal but well... that is then stored in custom control table. 
I have to access that ID value in the last step of the pipeline to update the record in my custom control table.